# Paging 3 - how to change paging source dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, paging, dagger-hilt

I need to be able to change the paging source dynamically.

A screen with 2 functions:

- 1st: Initially loads list of data
- 2nd: Search for a particular data

ViewModel:

```
class BlogsViewModel: BaseViewModel() {

    var blogs = Pager(PagingConfig(10)) {
        BlogsDataSource()
    }.liveData.cachedIn(viewModelScope)


    fun search(keyword: String) {
        blogs = Pager(PagingConfig(10)) {
            BlogsSearchDataSource("testing")
        }.liveData.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun getBlogs() {
        blogs = Pager(PagingConfig(10)) {
            BlogsDataSource()
        }.liveData.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

Whenever I call the "search" function nothing changes.
I tried using `adapter.refresh()` but didn't work

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 notifyDataSetChanged()
```